# How to structure scientific references into groups using R?

Tags: r, nlp, stringr

Lets imagine the following two references:

```
ref1 <- "Smith, A. L., Reganold, J. P., Jones, M. S., Orpet, R. J., Taylor, J. M., Thurman, J. H., Cornell, K. A., Olsson, R. L., Ge, Y., Kennedy, C. M., & Crowder, D. W. (2020). Landscape context affects the sustainability of organic farming systems. Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences, 117(6), 2870–2878. https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.1906909117"

ref2 <- "Muller, A., Schader, C., El-Hage Scialabba, N. et al. Strategies for feeding the world more sustainably with organic agriculture. Nat Commun 8, 1290 (2017). doi.org/10.1038/s41467-017-01410-w"
```

And I would like to group this data into (for example)

```
data.frame(first_author = c("Smith, A. L.","Reganold, J. P."), 
          second_author = c("Muller, A.","Schader, C."),
          year = c("2020","2017"),
          title = c("Landscape context affects the sustainability of organic farming systems","Strategies for feeding the world more sustainably with organic agriculture"), 
          journal = c("Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences","Nat Commun"),
          volume.issue = c("117(6)","8(1290)"),
          pages = c("2870–2878",NA),
          doi = c("https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.1906909117","doi.org/10.1038/s41467-017-01410-w"))
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first authors be Smith and Muller, not Smith and Reganold, while the second authors should be Reganold and Schader?

Comment: To achieve this you need NLP process, because you cannot assume when a missing value will appear. So, using NLP and then a similarity text algorithm, you will be able to see which field is really missing and which can be completed. In case you always know that there won't be NA values, then str_split by "." can solve the problem easily.

Comment: I have voted to close this question as needs more focus, because it is extremely challenging and the scope is too large to be answered in the Q&A format. We could trivially write code that addresses these two specific instances. However, when you go to apply it to your actual task, you will find that it does not work. This will result in an endless cycle of editing your question and an answer author having to address your next edge case.